# Adding merchants/sellers to magento site

Tags: magento, marketplace

We have to add sellers/merchants to our site.

It means, through our site, sellers have to sell the products & we have to get commission

from the sellers.

demo example : https://seller.flipkart.com/

If there are 5 sellers , buyer have to see all 5 sellers in checkout page or

related page. Also Buyers can check the nearest shop to buy the product using pin code or search box.

after they selecting nearest store, than products list should display.

IS there any good extension for this. please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

There are three good market place extension. You can check their features as per your requirement:

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Marketplace.html

https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace

https://www.apptha.com/magento/marketplace